# Lambda calculus isEven function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, lambda-calculus

So I'm learning about lambda calculus in Haskell, and I'm trying to implement an isEven function that returns true if it's even and false otherwise. I know that 0 is even and then 1 is odd and then each alternating number is the alternative of the one before i.e. if one is odd then 2 is even then 3 is odd. Could I have the isEven function check if the input is 0 and if it's not then somehow check if it's successor is even or odd?

Comment: It would help to see the precise construction you're working with. This is not my instinctive reaction on how to solve it.

Comment: what do you mean by the precise construction?

Comment: Yes you could, though `isEven 1176845632190017` would take quite some time to rin.

Comment: Actually, I think I would have to check the predecessor not the successor and then recurse to zero

Comment: @pythonhelpthrow Let's say you had some data type like `data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat`. Then `isEven :: Nat -> Bool` would look like `isEven Zero = True; isEven (Succ n) = not (isEven n)`. But you have some other data type or encoding for `Nat`; that's what's missing from your question.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that by "lambda calculus" you mean we're working with some Church-encoded numerals + booleans, and the "Haskell" part is mostly incidental to your question.

```
isEven = \n -> n flip True
flip = \x y z -> x z y
True = \x y -> x
False = \x y -> y
```

This operates slightly differently to how you express it.

Recall the Church numeral `n` means `n` iterated function applications. `flip` repeated an even # of times is `id`, thus `n flip == id` for even `n`, `n flip == flip` for odd `n`. Also, `flip True == False` and `flip False == True`. Thus the construction correctly encodes parity.